# maximum size of maxConnections for binding used with netTcp

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I am searching for the max. limit for the property maxConnections for a binding used with netTcpBinding?

Comment: Conceivably, because it's an `int`, the maximum value is `Int32.MaxValue` or `2,147,483,647`. In practice that's obviously unrealistic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MSDN: [NetTcpBinding.MaxConnections Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding.maxconnections%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the type is `Int32`, so the maximum value will be 2,147,483,647, as others have said.

The default value is 10.

Realistically, I wouldn't expect a maximum setting in this property to be used in a service or client, but if you need something more than 10 you have plenty of room.

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
 Int32.MaxValue =2,147,483,647
```

Get with this code:

```
   int maxConnections = binding.MaxConnections;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this answer your question, i have got something similar to your question

see here [High MaxConnections value and Out of Memory Exception](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a49251b7-53e9-4d7b-b9a6-7da1a6bb72ca/high-maxconnections-value-and-out-of-memory-exception)

> "**MaxConnections** has to do with the total number of open
>   connections on the service, regardless if the service is executing
>   anything for the connection."
>
> the MAX value differs from system to system depending upon
>   it's capacity and maybe OS as well.